# JToolBarHelper :: DeleteList - Does not work

Tags: joomla2.5

I created a **Joomla 2.5** custom component and load data to grid on administrator side. All data loaded and adding and editing work well. But deleting is not working. It gives following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function delete() on a non-object in 
C:\wamp\www\Joomla\libraries\joomla\application\component\controlleradmin.php on line 131
```

In view class I used `JToolBarHelper` for delete action as follows.

```
JToolBarHelper::deleteList('', 'regions.delete', 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE');
```

Comment: Have you found the solution for this issue? I have the same problem here

Comment: @PiotrK Thank you, that's the right solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem myself, and I've just figured it out. Look into your file corresponding to `admin/controllers/helloworlds.php`, there should be this line:

```
public function getModel($name = 'HelloWorld', $prefix = 'HelloWorldModel')
```

The first param's default value is the name of a single item (in your case, probably `Region`) and the second one contains the name of the component. So it  should be:

```
public function getModel($name = 'Region', $prefix = 'NameOfYourComponentModel')
```

I hope this helps also in your case. In the HelloWorld example, they use `HelloWorld` all over the code, both as the name of the component and the main view, so it's sometimes hard to distinguish which one is what.